# Uncaught TypeError: this.onSubmit is not a function in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, weather-api

I am trying to make a call to the [Open Source weather API](https://www.openweathermap.org/api) using React.

But I get the following error `App.js:59 Uncaught TypeError: this.onSubmit is not a function`

This is my api file:

```
import axios from 'axios';

var key = 'TK421';
var countryCode = 'us';

export const getWeatherByZip = zipCode => {
  return axios
    .get(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=${zipCode},${countryCode}&appid=${key}`)
    .then(resp => resp.data);
};
```

And this is my main/app file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import * as api from '../utils/api';

import '../scss/app.scss';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      zipcode: '',
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    var zip = event.target.value;
    this.setState(function() {
      return {
        zipcode: zip,
      };
    });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.onSubmit(
      api.getWeatherByZip(this.state.zipcode).then(
        function(zip) {
          this.setState(function() {
            return {
              zipcode: zip,
            };
          });
        }.bind(this)
      )
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
          <h2>Open Weather App</h2>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="one-half column">
              <label htmlFor="insertMode">Insert your location</label>
              <input
                className="u-full-width"
                placeholder="please enter your zipcode"
                type="text"
                autoComplete="off"
                value={this.state.zipcode}
                onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="one-half column">
              <label htmlFor="showMin">show minimum</label>
              <input type="checkbox" />
              <label htmlFor="showMax">show maximum</label>
              <input type="checkbox" />
              <label htmlFor="showMean">show mean</label>
              <input type="checkbox" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="two-half column">
              <button className="button-primary" type="submit" disabled={!this.state.zipcode}>
                Submit
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

How do I get the proper response back when inputing and submitting a form in react?

**UPDATE:**

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    api.getWeatherByZip(this.state.zipcode).then(
      function(zip) {
        console.log('zip', zip);

        this.setState(function() {
          return {
            zipcode: zip,
          };
        });
      }.bind(this)
    );
  }
```

And in my JSX:

```
 <div className="container">
        <form
          onSubmit={() => {
            this.handleSubmit;
          }}
        >
          <h2>Open Weather App</h2>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="one-half column">
              <label htmlFor="insertMode">Insert your location</label>
              <input
                className="u-full-width"
                placeholder="please enter your zipcode"
                type="text"
                autoComplete="off"
                value={this.state.zipcode}
                onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="one-half column">
              <label htmlFor="showMin">show minimum</label>
              <input type="checkbox" />
              <label htmlFor="showMax">show maximum</label>
              <input type="checkbox" />
              <label htmlFor="showMean">show mean</label>
              <input type="checkbox" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="two-half column">
              <button className="button-primary" type="submit" disabled={!this.state.zipcode}>
                Submit
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
```

Comment: in the handleSubmit you call this.onSubmit which is not defined in the code snippet you show us. also as stated. you dont need to bind this multiple times. best in the constructor then just call it normally. or if you want you could always use fat arrow functions that auto bind the lexical scope. so you wont need to call .bind(this) anymore. but as to the source of the error. like I said. in the handleSubmit you're calling this.onSubmit which doesnt look defined on this. maybe you wanted to call this.props.onSubmit or something?

Answer (score 2):

You have already bound the method `handleSubmit` to the forms `onsubmit` event, you don't need to wrap the content of this method in `this.onSubmit`. This fails, because this method is not defined in the class in your code.

By the way, your binding the `this` context two times in your code, once in your `onsubmit` event and once in your constructor. It is sufficient to do this only once, and the recommended place for it is in your constructor.

Comment: Can you provide an example? I tried that and still getting the same error?

Comment: this.onSubmit is not a function is still occuring even after the onSubmit call is removed in handleSubmit?

Comment: I updated my question with the updated code/markup. Now the page refreshes? Any insight?

Comment: You wrote ```onSubmit={() => {this.handleSubmit;}}```. This does not call the function handleSubmit. Write either ```onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}``` or ```onSubmit={e => this.handleSubmit(e)}```. The problem is that, if you are using a lambda (a => b), the right hand side is a code block which will be evaluated, and if you just write a function name there, the function will not be called. The alternative is to just write a reference to the function instead of a lambda, only in this case you can leave out the paranthesis because the function reference is handed over and is hen called.